# compiler gives invalid operands to binary expression error even if there is an overloaded stream insertion operator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn operator overloading and I get a below error

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Coefficient')
cout << (c + 4) << endl ;
```

I mentioned the line that causes the compiler to give an error. (last line in the main)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std ;

class Coefficient {
    private:
        double myValue ;
        mutable int myAccesses ;

    public:
        Coefficient (double initVal) {
            myValue = initVal ;
            myAccesses = 0 ;
        }

        double GetValue (void) const {
            myAccesses++ ;
            return myValue ;
        }

        bool operator= (double v) {
            myAccesses++ ;
            if (v < 0 || v > 1) {
                return false ;
            }
            myValue = v ;
            return true ;
        }

        bool operator+= (double addval) {
            return addValue(addval) ;
        }

        bool operator-= (double subval) {
            return addValue(-subval) ;
        }

        bool operator= (char * str) {
            if(!strcmp(str, "default")) {
                return operator=(0.5) ;
            } else if (!strcmp(str, "max")) {
                return operator=(0.0) ;
            } else if (!strcmp(str, "min")) {
                return operator=(1.0) ;
            } else {
                return false ;
            }
        }

        Coefficient operator+ (double d) {
            Coefficient sum{ this->myValue + d} ;
            return sum ;
        }
    private:
        bool addValue (double v) {
            myAccesses++ ;
            if (myValue + v < 0 || myValue + v> 1) {
                return false ;
            }
            myValue += v ;
            return true ;
        }
} ;

Coefficient operator+ (double leftval, Coefficient rightval) {
    return rightval + leftval ;
}

ostream & operator<< (ostream & output, Coefficient & holder) {
    output << (holder.GetValue()) ;
    return output ;
}

int main (void) {
     Coefficient c{0.5} ;
     cout << c << "\t";

     c = 0.75 ;
     cout << c << endl ;

     c = const_cast<char *>("max") ;
     cout << c << endl ;

     c = const_cast<char *>("default") ;
     cout << c << endl ;

     c = (c + 4) ;
     cout << c << endl ;

     cout << (c + 4) << endl ; // compiler gives error because of this line
}
```

I do overload the stream insertion operator and addition operator, and when I delete the last line, I can use my custom class with stream insertion operator and it prints a value.

As you can see at the end of the main, when I assigned the result of the summation to the variable, and then use the variable with stream insertion operator, I could print the value. But when I tried to use summation without assigning the variable, it gives an error.

Why does the compiler give that error? Why the compiler does not find proper overloaded function without assigning to the variable?

I am using mac os big sur. I use clang version 13.0.0

Comment: Make your stream operator receive a `const Coefficient &`.  Currently it's non-const which means it cannot resolve a _rvalue_ which is the case when you construct a temporary with `c + 4`.  Get in the habit of always being const-correct.  Any time you pass a reference, think "will my function modify this data?" -- if the answer is no, make it const.

Comment: Side-note: in C++, functions with no arguments should be declared with empty parentheses.  _i.e_ Do not write `double GetValue(void) const;` but instead `double GetValue() const;` -- same with `main`.  A good C++ compiler should complain about writing void explicitly in the parameter list.

Comment: @paddy It is specifically allowed to use a non-dependent `void` as only parameter to a function to denote an empty parameter list, just unconventional. I don't think compilers warn about it even with e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @paddy thank you for answers and suggestion. It solves but I don't understand why stream operator works with const Coefficient &? Is temporary variable const(I don't think it is const but)? The void suggestion, does it create any problem to write void? I am embedded developer and I use C a lot. So I prefer to use void for no argument funciton.

Comment: @AhmetDundar "*Is temporary variable const*" - No. A temporary can be modified under the right code. However, a `reference-to-non-const` cannot bind to a temporary, whereas a `reference-to-const` can. A non-`const` object can always be upgraded to a `const` object, but the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your stream output operator accepts a reference to a `Coefficient`:

```
ostream & operator<< (ostream & output, Coefficient & holder) {
    output << holder.GetValue();
    return output;
}
```

This works in the naive case, when you have some variable of type `Coefficient` and you output it.

```
cout << c;   //<-- c is an lvalue
```

But there's a subtle thing going on here.  The reference is what's called an *lvalue* -- that is, something that can be modified.  The reason why this works is because you're allowed to modify `c` because it's non-const and exists in the stack in your `main` function.

Now, consider the problem call:

```
cout << (c + 4);   //<-- (c + 4) is an rvalue
```

The way `c + 4` was created was via a value returned from your `operator+` overload.  The return value is a temporary, because it's not actually being stored in a variable anywhere.  Instead, it's created as a temporary that is used as an operand.  The temporary is what's called an *rvalue*.  The C++ standard prevents a program from holding non-const references to *rvalues* (a slight exception to this being *rvalue references*, which you are not using here and are not appropriate for this problem).

And so, the compiler error here is an overload resolution issue.  You made a temporary value with `c + 4` but there is no function that can take it as an argument, nor is there any way to automatically convert it to match any other operator overload.

To correct the issue, you need to either *copy* it (make the parameter a non-reference), or pass it as a *const reference*.  Usually, the latter is preferable:

```
ostream & operator<< (ostream & output, const Coefficient & holder) {
    output << holder.GetValue();
    return output;
}
```

This will fix the overload resolution problem, and since you have already correctly declared `.GetValue()` as const there should be no other issues.  But, if you had not made that `GetValue` function const, you would get an error.

Basic rules of thumb for const-correctness:

- if a function will not modify a parameter passed as a reference, make the reference const.
- if a member function will not modify the object, make the function const.

Answer (score -1):

`(c + 4)` is an rvalue (in type `Coefficient&&`) and it cannot be captured by `Coefficient&`).

Try to add another overload function like:

```cpp
ostream & operator<< (ostream & output, Coefficient && holder);
```